# Using inequality relations to prove one inequality

Tags: inequality

We are given positive values $w_1, s_1, w_2, s_2$. We know that $w_1 - s_2 \geq w_2 - s_1$, we need to show that $C + w_2 \leq s_1$, where $C$ is positive integer.

How to show this, which inequality relations can we use here. I tried rewriting the first expression in form: $w_1 + s_1 \geq w_2 + s_2$, however I cannot think of a way to merge those two expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

$$w_1 - s_2 \geq w_2 - s_1 \implies s_1 \ge\, w_2\, + s_2 \, -w_1\implies \boxed{s_1 \ge w_2 +C} \quad \text{ where C =} s_2 -w_1$$